# Can Bulma's image element use aspect ratio as a crop / mask?

Tags: bulma

I'm using the card component in Bulma and I want the card image to have a 16:9 aspect ratio. However, the images will be coming in dynamically, so I won't always be able to resize the images to ensure their dimensions.

So, what I'm hoping is that the image element could act like a crop or mask. If, for example, the image itself is a square, the top and bottom would simply be masked out. For example...

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-16by9">
      <img src="a square image goes here" alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">...</div>
</div>
```

When I try this, though, it distorts the image. I could play around with some overrides, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something about Bulma's image element or helpers before I do that. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't sound like there is a great way to do it using only Bulma, per https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2023.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah, looks like I'll need to add an override. Seems like height:100%; object-fit: cover; will do the trick. Thanks for the reply :-)